# How to use window.onload function to assign a validation callback function

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, callback

Hi there I am busy setting up a Form validation with javascript. 
I was wondering if someone knew how to use window.onload function to assign a validation callback function. The javascript needs to be in it's own file.

Comment: window.onload = function();

Answer (score 1):

simply assign your validation callback in the onload function body like this

```
yourform.onsubmit=function(){
    return your_validation_func();
}
```